# sbt 0.13 and Eclipse integration - What is "eclipse" and why is it not inspectable?

Tags: sbt, sbteclipse, sbt-0.13

I have a (Java-based) Play-2.3.10/sbt-0.13.9 project. In my global `.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt` I have

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.4.0")
```

I start sbt's console. I type `inspect compile`. I get

```
[info] Task: sbt.inc.Analysis
[info] Description:
[info]  Compiles sources.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/home/dh/workspace/ebus/}ebus/compile:compile
[...]
```

I type `inspect eclipse`. I get

```
[error] Not a valid project ID: eclipse
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: eclipsePreTasks, deliver, eclipseCreateSrc)
[error] inspect eclipse
[error]                ^
```

Why? I mean, I was of the opinion that eventually everything is a task in sbt - and therefore everything is inspectable. Where am I wrong and how do I get more information about what is going on when I type `eclipse` in the console?